# UIImage in TableVIew moves when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, swift3

I've a dynamic tableView that contains an `UIImage` and a label.
I've done a get call in order to get some information (to fill label and images), included links to images that i programmatically set to the `UIImage` with this code:

**Code Snippet :**

```
if let url = NSURL(string: chiesa.foto) { //chiesa.foto is taken from GET req
   if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
     chiesa.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)! //chiesa.image is an UIImage
   }
}
```

All is correct, but when i press on a row, in order to see details, the image change position of 10-11 px to the right, and when i press the back button (in the Details view) the image is still in the "changed position" (so, 10-11 px to the right).

This is the TableViewController code, under "viewDidLoad" method (that only get data from my DB):

**Code Snippet:**

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return chiese.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChieseTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChieseTableViewCell

    let chiesa = chiese[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelNome.text = chiesa.nome
    if(cell.photoImageView == nil){
        print("nil")
    }else{
        cell.photoImageView.image = chiesa.image
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "selectedChiesa" {
        var nextScene =  segue.destination as! ChiesaSelezionataViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let nomeChiesa = chiese[indexPath.row].nome
            let storiaChiesa = chiese[indexPath.row].storia
            nextScene.nome = nomeChiesa
            nextScene.storia = storiaChiesa
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your code with didSelectMethod

Comment: @Volodymyr I didn't implement this "override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" method on my view, because I had a problem with it (if implemented, when I select cell, it execute 2 segue and I don't know why).

Comment: than paste method that handles your taps

Comment: @Volodymyr i've edited my post

Comment: You were talking about pressing on a row. How are you checking when it was pressed? Can I see logic when you are trying to see details? Your code I mean

Comment: @Volodymyr I didn't write any code for the cell pressed. I've only do it with the storyboard (created a new View Controller, Control-drag from the TableViewCell to the new View Controller and changed identifier to the "show segue") after this, I've written the "segue" code, in order to pass data to the new View Controller

Comment: Code looks fine, need to look into project. Try checking constraints before and after pressing. Are they same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Problems were Costraints. I've just changed some costraints and it works!

Thank you @Volodymyr